# Any ideas on centering these previous/ next buttons? Previous posts have not helps

Tags: css

Looking to center these next and previous posts for my Shopify Blog page. Any luck, tried tons from other posts with no luck.

```
<div class="previous_next_buttons">
  <a href="{{ blog.previous_article }}" class="btn">
    Previous post     
  </a>
  <a href="{{ blog.next_article }}" class="btn">
    Next post   
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't indent correctly so the code I used wasn't showing up. This is my first post, sorry for the confusion. It should be showing now. I have Googled and looked through countless other SO posts, trying their solutions but none have worked so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be the following:

```css
.previous_next_buttons {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.btn:first-of-type {
  margin-right:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="previous_next_buttons">
  <a href="{{ blog.previous_article }}" class="btn">
    Previous post     
  </a>
  <a href="{{ blog.next_article }}" class="btn">
    Next post   
  </a>

</div>
```

But it's hard to tell as we don't know which css is already applied to the classes.